# What do the Action Points in the equipment section mean?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

There are action points shown in inventory menu for each equipment piece. Does that mean that, for example, if it shows 5AP - I need to have that 5AP to wear that piece of equipment? Seems that that number is not a penalty as it doesn't reduce my total action points in battle.

Comment: AP is only for battles, I forget since it's been a while but I am kind of sure that is just the cost of AP it would take to pick it up in the middle of a battle. Likely higher due to the weight/size of the item.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

n_palum is pretty much right about the meaning. It's a feature that resembles standard role-playing games where it counts equipping an item, like a weapon or armor, as an action. Thus, to equip a chestplate with 5AP during battle, it'll require you to have 5AP available to spend during a turn.

[This thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/170517-divinity-original-sin-enhanced-edition/72739179) backs this up.

> I think it's how many AP it costs to equip during battle...?
>
> This exactly. I switched a piece of equipment in battle earlier and realized it cost ap to switch.

Comment: If it is for equipping then it may be worth noting that picking up new items/equipment during battle will likely have different AP costs, which I think are visible when hovering over items on the battlefield.

Comment: @n_palum I'm not sure about there being an AP cost to *pick up* items during a battle other than the movement AP to get there... but why would you be picking up items mid-battle??

Comment: If I remember correctly from when I played it that was something you could do and I am pretty sure it costs a bit of AP to pick things up during a fight. I played the game coop so sometimes we would run and nab cool loot on our turn right before the fight ended to beat the friend to it as a joke... or if there were arrows/throwables that could help in the current combat that were dropped by enemies

Comment: @n_palum ah, survival takes a back seat to "trolling your friend," so I definitely understand

Comment: There's also a situation where you want to change your equipment to target specific enemies/situations.  For example, against an enemy which heals from fire damage you might switch to a weaker, non-fire weapon and then switch back once it is dead.  Also, picking up and moving objects is sometimes useful to block an enemy's path or stop an environmental hazard grate, or unblock it when the enemy gets to it.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian I understand the utility of changing armor in a battle, but I haven't gotten far enough to have come across a time where picking up items would be a worthwhile use of my turn :P I was just picturing picking up money or loot.

Comment: @Vemonus Yeah, I can think of some contrived examples of putting an item in your inventory, teleporting, and dropping the item to move it further than you can throw it.  I think it comes down to your point that the game is meant to play like a classic RPG, so it allows you to have as many options as possible, even if some are almost always pointless or suboptimal.